# Sub query result and all table fields in one HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, hql

I have POJOs like this:

```
 public Class Car{
   private String color;
   private Set<Tire> tires;
   ...
 }

 public class Tire {
   private String model;
   ...
 }

 public class CarDTO extends Car{
   private Integer tireCount;
   ...
 }
```

And I need HQL query like this:

```
 select 
  ( select cast(  nvl(sum(d.count),0)  as integer ) from e.tires d ) as tireCount,
 e
 from Car.class e
```

but when i use `Query.setResultTransformer(CarDTO.class)` , raise error bellow:

```
Could not find setter for 1 on class CarDTO
```

I inspect result and found that Hql treat `e` like object and my query return two object.A Integer and a Car. But how get all Car.class property value without changes POJOs?

something like e.* in sql

Comment: If I understood correctly, are you reusing the CarDTO in another places on the system?

Comment: @Dherik Not now. CarDTO just a value object for store hql result. buy in feature maybe reuse in some other places.